# Update field with $currentDate on pymongo not working

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am looking to update the field "UpdatedDate" with the current date using `$currentDate` function but it's not working. The code below gives me the error:

> OperationFailure: Invalid modifier specified $currentDate

```
db.BroHist.update({"Url":"about:blank","SiteType":{"$exists":True}},
                     {"$currentDate": {"UpdatedDate": {"$type":"date"}},
                     "$set": { "Host": "NewPage", "SiteType": "Other","SubSiteType": "NewPage Manual"}},
                     upsert=False,multi=True)
```

I used this q&a to come up with the $currentDate code: [Insert the $currentDate on mongodb with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814040/insert-the-currentdate-on-mongodb-with-pymongo)

Comment: What mongodb version are you using?

Comment: @alecxe thanks for replying. I'm using version 2.6

Comment: Your example works perfectly for me. I tested on MongoDB 2.6.7. $currentDate is new in MongoDB 2.6.0.

Comment: Just to confirm - this is on pymongo it worked for you? or on something like Robomongo directly on the DB?

Comment: @BernieHackett we realized that our test db was an older version thats why it didn't work. thank you, it's working!